# Co-meager set in open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

**Definition**. Let $X$ be a topological space and $U\subset X$ an open set. We say that $A$ is meager in $U$ if $A\cap U$ is meager in $X.$ Also, $A$ is co-meager in $U$ if $U\setminus A$ is meager.

Let $\Bbb B$ be a countable basis of $\Bbb R.$ Let $\{P^I\subset I\colon I\in\Bbb B\}$ be pairwise disjoint meager set of $\Bbb R$. Then $$I\setminus\bigcup_{I\in\Bbb B} P^I$$ is co-meager in $I.$ Indeed, it is enough  to show that $\bigcup_{I\in\Bbb B} P^I= I\setminus\bigg(I\setminus\bigcup_{I\in\Bbb B} P^I\bigg)$ is meager in $I.$ To see this we need to check that $\bigcup_{I\in\Bbb B} P^I\cap I$ is meager in $\Bbb R.$ Of course, this is true since $P^I=\bigcup_{I\in\Bbb B} P^I\cap I$ is meager in $\Bbb R$ by the assumption.

> Is that true? I just need to make sure  that I used the definition in the correct way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I$ is Polish and so a countable union of meagre sets in it is still meagre. That's the whole proof.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, Thank for your comment. $P^I$ is meager in $X$ not $I$

Comment: @00GB if it’s meagre in $X$ it still is meagre in any open set.

Comment: Henno Brandsma , Yeah, I missed this , But is not the another way around. right?